# 6 girls and 6 boys arrangement

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

There are 6 boys and 6 girls , Boys have a note of 20 dollars while girls have a note of 10 dollars . They stand in a queue to boy a theater ticket that costs 10 dollar , if initially the cashier has no money then the number of ways in which they may stand so that no one waits for a change is y*((6!)^2) . Find y
{each boy and girl is unique }

Comment: This is quite an interesting question; what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the number of \$10 notes $i$ held by the cashier:

- When a girl buys a ticket $i$ always increases by one
- When a boy buys a ticket $i$ decreases by one, and the boy will be left waiting for change if $i=0$ to begin with
- $i$ is zero to begin with

Thus there is a bijection between classic Dyck paths of semilength $6$ – the lattice paths from $(0,0)$ to $(6,6)$ with $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ steps not going above the diagonal – and the admissible boy-girl sequences. The answer $y$ already has the $(6!)^2$ factor arising from permuting boys and girls factored out, so the answer is the sixth Catalan number, $132$.

Comment: Well i didn't know about catalan number at first but now i learnt it . Thanks